# how to force chrome task manager to end a task

Tags: google-chrome, task-manager, chromebook

I am using an administrator-restricted Chromebook and things can often get out of hand, so naturally like any PC user I'd open the task manager (chrome task manager) and when I go to close the problematic tab with force, the [End Task] button is grayed out and unusable. while id be fine with waiting it out from time to time, it gets annoying when my Chromebook fully resets due to stress after 5 minutes of time I could have been able to use to shut down the program. in short - how can i get around the grayed-out "End Task" button and just force it to close in another way?

thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sadly but you can't do anything in this case. There are several users who are facing the same issue in chromebooks. At last, if you can get these administrator-restricted permissions removed then it may help you because the End Task button is mostly blocked by the administrator.

And always try to keep your chromebook's cache and other temporary data cleared because sometime this may also create an issue.